# Taking sub-arrays in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I get a sub array in Haskell?

Comment: Do you know how to get an array in the first place?  What array library are you talking about?  Data.Vector?  Data.Array?  This question really needs fleshed out.

Comment: @TomMD subArray of Data.Array

Comment: Data.Array is rather clumsy and has no fusion, I suggest you look to Data.Vector for future array needs.

Comment: `newArray_ (0,x) :: IO (IOArray Int Sub)` :-P

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you in the end ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for is the '*Derived arrays*' section in the Data.Array documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array.html#5
which houses the function:

> **ixmap** :: (Ix i, Ix j) => (i, i) -> (i -> j) -> Array j e -> Array i e
>
> ixmap allows for transformations on array indices. It may be thought of as providing function composition on the right with the mapping that the original array embodies.
>
> A similar transformation of array values may be achieved using fmap from the Array instance > of the Functor class.

The following code:

```
ixmap newBounds trans backingArray
```

would return an array with bounds `newBounds`, and when indexed with `!i`, the *index transformation function* is applied onto the index `i` before being used to index `backingArray`.

---

**Example** if you had the array "Hello World" (helloWorldArray below) and you want to only see "ell" as a derived *zero-based* (sub-)array:

```
> let helloWorldArray = listArray (0,length str - 1) str    -- 0-based array
     where str = "Hello World"

> let ellArray = ixmap (0,2) succ helloWorldArray           -- also 0-based array

> ellArray ! 0
'e'
> ellArray ! 1
'l'
> ellArray ! 2
'l'
```

Here we say that our new array `ellArray` has indices from `0` through `2`. Our index transformation is simply to add one (`succ`), because we want to map the index range `[0..2]` to `[1..3]` in the original `helloWorldArray`.

Of course, `ixmap` is abstract enough to capture any index transformations: even as to view 2 dimensional arrays as 1 dimensional arrays and vice-versa. It's better to think of it as creating a 'view' onto array data *rather* than a 'sub-array' function.

For more examples you can look here: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputarray/ixmap_f.html

Answer (score 4):

Taking sub-arrays using the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package is probably the easiest approach (assuming your question isn't actually asking about taking sub-lists).

The relevant functions from the general vector/array interface is:

- [slice](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:6) `:: Vector v a => Int -> Int -> v a -> v a`

but you should also know about take and drop. slice takes a index and length, and extracts the sub-array.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any direct way to get a sub-array (i.e. slice), but here's one way to do it via an intermediate list.

```
import Data.Array

subArray :: Int -> Int -> Array -> Array
subArray i j a = listArray (0,j-i) $ map (a!) [i..j]
```